# ajax request not sending any data ASP.NET MVC project with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm fairly new to asp.net MVC but am baffled as to why my request isn't working.

I'm trying to send an ajax request with jquery as per:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var total = 0,
        share = $('div.share'),
        googlePlusUrl = "https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url=http://bookboon.com" + $(location).attr('pathname');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: "smelly",
            traditional: true,
            url: share.data('proxy'),
            success: function(junk) {
                //var $junk = junk.match(regex);
                console.log(junk);
            },
            error: function (xhr, errorText) {
                console.log('Error ' + xhr.responseType);
            },
        });
    }, 4000);
```

And set a line in my RouteConfig as:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "services/{site}/proxy", new { controller = "Recommendations", action = "Proxy" });
```

The markup has a data-attribute value as:

```
<div class="share" data-proxy="@Url.Action("Proxy", "Recommendations")">
```

And my Proxy action method starts with:

```
public ActionResult Proxy(string junk)
```

The problem is that the `junk` parameter is always null. I can see in the debug output that the route seems to correctly redirect to this method when the page loads (as per jQuery's document ready function), but I cannot seem to send any data.

I tried sending simple data ("smelly") but I don't receive that neither.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model binder will be looking for a parameter in the request called `junk`, however you're sending only a plain string. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: { junk: "smelly" }, // <- note the object here
    traditional: true,
    url: share.data('proxy'),
    success: function(junk) {
        //var $junk = junk.match(regex);
        console.log(junk);
    },
    error: function (xhr, errorText) {
        console.log('Error ' + xhr.responseType);
    },
});
```

Comment: That alacrity in response and you bothered to correct the spacing.. have all of my babies good sir